# Generic term for 'one who is being told a story'

Tags: terminology

So we have the term "storyteller" for anyone who is telling a story, be it via a book, verbally, the silver screen, or some other media.

Do we have a generic term for the audience *specific* to storytelling?

The generic 'audience' would cover anyone from somebody watching the 5 o'clock news, to somebody reading a dental pamphlet, to somebody reading a work of fiction, and I'd like something more specific.

Comment: listeners, or heeders. for more visual storytelling: spectators, viewers, theatergoers, showgoers

Comment: also, storyteller refers to a person, so you wouldn't call a 'movie, or a play, or an opera' a storyteller.

Comment: @V0ight I don't believe I implied that the story was the storyteller, but the '[person] who is telling a story.'

Comment: just clarifying because the reason there's no specific word for *story-receiver* is that the *receiver* part depends on the medium in question, but the medium in question is not necessarily a person. @Nex Terren

Comment: You're getting some odd answers.  How do you want to use this term?  That might help if we knew in what context the term would be used?

Comment: *storytellees*, no doubt. Not to be confused with *storyteletubbies*.

Comment: Just commenting to throw in the phrase "dear reader/dear readers" - very well used, but specific to reading - so I can find this post later when I think of the right term!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want a more 'medium-neutral' term for this, consider these options:

[story-receiver](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22story+recipient%22&lr=lang_en&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1960%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2016&tbm=bks#lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en%2Ccdr:1%2Ccd_min:1%2F1%2F1960%2Ccd_max:12%2F31%2F2016&tbm=bks&q=%22story+receiver%22)

[story-recipient](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22story+recipient%22&lr=lang_en&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1960%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2016&tbm=bks)

[story-experiencer](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22story+recipient%22&lr=lang_en&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1960%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2016&tbm=bks#lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en%2Ccdr:1%2Ccd_min:1%2F1%2F1960%2Ccd_max:12%2F31%2F2016&tbm=bks&q=%22story+experiencer%22)

.

[narrative-receiver](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22story+recipient%22&lr=lang_en&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1960%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2016&tbm=bks#lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en%2Ccdr:1%2Ccd_min:1%2F1%2F1960%2Ccd_max:12%2F31%2F2016&tbm=bks&q=%22narrative+receiver%22)

[narrative-recipient](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22story+recipient%22&lr=lang_en&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1960%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2016&tbm=bks#lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en%2Ccdr:1%2Ccd_min:1%2F1%2F1960%2Ccd_max:12%2F31%2F2016&tbm=bks&q=%22narrative+recipient%22)

[narrative-experiencer](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22story+recipient%22&lr=lang_en&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1960%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2016&tbm=bks#lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en%2Ccdr:1%2Ccd_min:1%2F1%2F1960%2Ccd_max:12%2F31%2F2016&tbm=bks&q=%22narrative+experiencer%22)

---

> [*"The focus of narrative analyses has been on the **story and the teller**. More attention needs to be paid to the role of the **story receiver** in creating narrative meaning"*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PJYbAQAAIAAJ&q=%22story+receiver%22&dq=%22story+receiver%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSrJbR1-7NAhWG4SYKHUV1DCkQ6AEIKDAD)
>
> [*"We can study narrative from the vantage point of the **storyteller or the story receiver**..."* *"The **storyteller** chooses what story information to present and to omit. The **story receiver** pieces together the information presented as well as hinted at and creates the story in her or his imagination."*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SF8cAQAAIAAJ&q=%22story+receiver%22&dq=%22story+receiver%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSrJbR1-7NAhWG4SYKHUV1DCkQ6AEIKzAE)
>
> [*"...on the part of both participants (**story-teller and audience**) that indeed a story is being told, that there is present in one place a **story-teller and a story-receiver**"*](https://books.google.com/books?id=1JCGAAAAIAAJ&q=%22story+receiver%22&dq=%22story+receiver%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSrJbR1-7NAhWG4SYKHUV1DCkQ6AEILzAF)
>
> [*"At these moments, one can hardly distinguish between the **story giver and the story receiver**, for it's in the shared experience that the dragon appears."*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5I5LAAAAYAAJ&q=%22story+receiver%22&dq=%22story+receiver%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSrJbR1-7NAhWG4SYKHUV1DCkQ6AEIPDAI)
>
> [*"The concept of point of view involves the relationship of the **narrator to his story and to the story's receiver**."*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cXvXAAAAMAAJ&q=%22story+receiver%22&dq=%22story+receiver%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP1I2_3u7NAhUEVD4KHaRSDS84ChDoAQgbMAA)
>
> [The circuit of communication is now completed: **narrator, story, receiver**, response. The "story", however, need not have plot or action.](https://books.google.com/books?id=vto5AQAAIAAJ&q=%22story+receiver%22&dq=%22story+receiver%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP1I2_3u7NAhUEVD4KHaRSDS84ChDoAQgnMAM)
>
> [*"The opposite of a **storyteller**, she was a **story receiver**."*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TYIhAQAAIAAJ&q=%22story+receiver%22&dq=%22story+receiver%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP1I2_3u7NAhUEVD4KHaRSDS84ChDoAQg0MAU)

---

> [*"Narrative has the power to create such worlds, imagined communities, or mythical nations, which on certain occasions can supplant the “real” world in the mind of the **story recipient**.*"](https://books.google.com/books?id=Fn3QuVZH2CQC&pg=PA53&dq=%22story+recipient%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU5fOZ5O7NAhVGID4KHU1oAwYQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=%22story%20recipient%22&f=false)
>
> [*"Most narrative researchers consider storytelling to be unlike everyday conversation in that the **teller** monologically performs narration, **an audience exists as story recipient**..."*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Advjvyv7yLAC&pg=PT117&dq=%22story+recipient%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUwOu04O7NAhVBPj4KHSULAxc4ChDoAQgzMAU#v=onepage&q=%22story%20recipient%22&f=false)

---

> [*"It is significant that Munro often changes between first- and third-person narration in successive versions of a story without changing our sense of the **story's experiencer**."*](https://books.google.com/books?id=opkfAQAAIAAJ&q=%22story+experiencer%22&dq=%22story+experiencer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb94Hs4e7NAhUCSD4KHWa9DSkQ6AEIHDAA)

---

> [*"3) locate and describe, narrate into existence, **an audience as narrative receiver**, and, by extension, give form to a conception of the world."*](https://books.google.com/books?id=z31IAQAAIAAJ&q=%22narrative+receiver%22&dq=%22narrative+receiver%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAvYOe4u7NAhXKaD4KHfXTCCAQ6AEIJTAC)

---

> [*"The metaphor, whether cultural or private, was heard by the listener as an element of performance style — something that made the oral performance an emotionally satisfying experience for **both storyteller and narrative recipient** alike."*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PLobAQAAIAAJ&q=%22narrative+recipient%22&dq=%22narrative+recipient%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxvuy74u7NAhVDcj4KHZl4D-I4ChDoAQggMAE)
>
> [*"For example, directly addressing the reader normally compels us to acknowledge our role as **narrative recipient**; but these addresses are minimal in the early chapters of Jane Eyre, though they increase dramatically near the end of the novel,..."*](https://books.google.com/books?id=529aAAAAMAAJ&q=%22narrative+recipient%22&dq=%22narrative+recipient%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi987CX5u7NAhWFFz4KHemUA5Y4ChDoAQgjMAI) ~ *Charlotte Brontë and the **Storyteller's Audience***

---

> [*"Finally, we must distinguish between the “incident narrative” (that of the “**narrative experiencer**”) and the “courtroom narrative” (that of the in-court legal **storyteller**). "*](https://books.google.com/books?id=O9QtzB8DM18C&pg=PA18&dq=%22narrative+experiencer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg2YXQ4u7NAhWCPD4KHXWDAxYQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22narrative%20experiencer%22&f=false)

Comment: Did you mean to include the hyphens in your original listing of terms? It seems that most of your examples (correctly) don't include a hyphen in between the two words

Comment: @Nick Weinberg ~ It's a personal stylistic choice; the hyphens make it seem as if the two words go together more, compared to without them. Anyway there's no rule against it. The third link uses *story-teller*, along with *story-receiver*..... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storyteller ("Storyteller, Story Teller, or Story-Teller may refer to")

Comment: refer to the section 'Compound nouns': http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/hyphen-american  The general rule is that if the compound nouns are very common in speech, they're usually going to be either combined or separated by a space. If they're uncommon, hyphens are acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I could find, we refer to the generic audience as a version of the verb used to receive the story suffixed with -er.

Watching the 5 o'clock news makes you a **viewer**.
Reading a dental pamphlet or work of fiction makes you a **reader**.
Listening to a story makes you a **listener**.

See **Audience** for examples — [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/audience) (bolding mine)

> *noun* 1. the group of spectators at a public event; **listeners** or **viewers** collectively, as in attendance at a theater or concert:
>   *The audience was respectful of the speaker's opinion.*

Comment: The OP wants *not* to include pamphlet-readers and news-watchers.

Comment: Right. Which is why audience isn't the term I suggested.

Comment: You offered very specific terms (tied to the specific media), which I appreciate, but I was hoping for something with roughly the same level of specificity as "storyteller."

Comment: Ah. How about storylistener? Might be a bit hammy, haha.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be in common usage, but consider ***storygoer***, formed on analogy with with *theatergoer*, *moviegoer*, *filmgoer*, and *concertgoer*. It means:

> a person who entertains a story.

This word is used. For example, it is used in the following passage:

> Stories always have a situation, however minimal, whether given through description, narration, dialogue, action, or otherwise. Beyond merely suspending disbelief in order to entertain a story, the **storygoer** who holds nothing back allows the imagined to gain an actual reality.
>
> [Soderquist, *Kierkegaard on Dialogical Education* (2016)](https://books.google.com/books?id=CiJsDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA23&dq=%22storygoer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU1Munze7NAhXCCD4KHQuKCBgQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22storygoer%22&f=false)

An alternative is ***storyhearer***, which is generally used to mean anyone who entertains a story, spoken *or* written. This definition is evidenced by example occurrences [here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22storyhearer%22).

Another alternative is ***storyship***, formed on analogy with *readership* and *listenership*. But *storyship* would refer to the collective audience, not a single person.